# MinGW: undefined reference to `__mingw_glob' when using ws2_32 library

Tags: c++, eclipse, mingw, winsock

I am trying to do a little test with Winsock functions. I am using MinGW c++ compiler, in Eclipse IDE. minggw32-base installed version is 2013072200, eclipse version is Kepler SR1 Build 20130919-0819

My Program looks as follows (actually not doing anything right now..):

SocketTest_Server.hpp:

```
#ifndef SOCKETTEST_SERVER_HPP_
#define SOCKETTEST_SERVER_HPP_

#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <winsock2.h>

#endif /* SOCKETTEST_SERVER_HPP_ */
```

SocketTest_Server.cpp:

```
#include "SocketTest_Server.hpp"
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    cout << "Test" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I added the library paths the following way:

Project Properties --> C/C++ General --> Paths and Symbols --> Libraries: added ws2_32
Project Properties --> C/C++ General --> Paths and Symbols --> Library Paths: added C:/MinGW/lib

When compiling now, I get the following error message (shown with complete compile command line):

```
g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -o SocketTest_Server.o "..\\SocketTest_Server.cpp"
g++ -LC:/MinGW/lib -o SocketTest_Server.exe SocketTest_Server.o -lws2_32 
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/lib/crt2.o:crt1.c:(.text+0x376): undefined reference to `__mingw_glob'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/lib/crt2.o:crt1.c:(.text+0x47d): undefined reference to `__mingw_glob'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Can someone please show me what I am doing wrong here? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Try using MinGW-w64 (32-bit, if you must). You can get it through [the installer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win32/Personal%20Builds/mingw-builds/installer/mingw-w64-install.exe). You should be able to install it in the same location as your current MinGW install (after first removing the other toolchain, perhaps by renaming `C:\MinGW` to `C:\MinGW-backup`. Then Eclipse won't need its settings changed.

Comment: Hold on, I'll make it into an answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

This issue could be caused by numerous things, but I believe you have an outdated toolchain.

In any case, you can upgrade to the more recent and more complete MinGW-w64, which provide a 32- and 64-bit toolchain (ARM incoming) with GCC on Windows.
You can get it by using [the installer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win32/Personal%20Builds/mingw-builds/installer/mingw-w64-install.exe).

In your case, I suggest just removing everything in `C:\MinGW` and installing the MinGW-w64 (32-bit) toolchain in that same exact location. Eclipse won't even know what happened and should need no settings changed.